# React native using class components error

Tags: react-native

I am just getting started with React native and I came across a rather unexpected bug. Consider the code below

```js
export default class RecipePage extends Component {
    state = {
        ingredients: ["apple", "orange"]
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <ShowRecipes ingredients={this.state.ingredients} />
            </View>
         )
    }
}
```

```js
class ShowRecipes extends Component {
   render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>This is inside ShowRecipes</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
export default ShowRecipes
```

I get an error below which points to `<ShowRecipes ingredients={this.state.ingredients} />`
"TypeError: undefined is not an object"

I am getting this error and I am not able to figure out what's causing it. Can someone please help fix this mistake.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: On which line of code this error occurs?

Comment: "This error is located at: in ShowRecipes (at RecipePage.js 10)"  (The line number points to the <ShowRecipes /> component in RecipePage)

Comment: how did you import ShowRecipes ? import {ShowRecipes } from '../' or import ShowRecipes  from '../'?

Comment: @SagharMirali  import ShowRecipes from './ShowRecipes'

Comment: Please, show us a copy of the module with functional component representation.

Comment: but your code is working fine, I copied it to my project and no error acured, please provide a full code snack repo

Comment: @НиколайГольцев I'm sorry actually now the error is there in functional component as well

Comment: @SagharMirali Can you please tell how can I do that...

Comment: Try to export ```ShowRecipes``` as ```export default class ShowRecipes...``` instead of a separate line.

Comment: write it here: https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: Sorry i think this was a problem with Expo CLI. I tried the code later and now it works. Appreciate your replies and thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You should put State in the contructor to get like this this.state.something
Try this code.

```
export default class RecipePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
         ingredients: ["apple", "orange"]
      }
   }
}
```